# Expand not working from Breeze 1.4 with EF 5 db first

Tags: entity-framework, odata, breeze

The situation is that the expand function from breeze does not return any entities.

Background:
Using a legacy db to which there is no suitable driver for ef 6. Only ef 5. So db first is used.
Breeze version is 1.4.8
EF version is 5.0.0

What works:
From LinqPad the include() works and everything returns as they should.

```
Invoicings.Take(10).Include("MyInvoice").AsNoTracking()
```

The AsNoTracking() is there cause otherwise this returns an error:

> The value of a property that is part of an object's key does not match
>   the corresponding property value stored in the ObjectContext.  This
>   can occur if properties that are part of the key return inconsistent
>   or incorrect values or if DetectChanges is not called after changes
>   are made to a property that is part of the key.

The Controller (api) offers the Invoicings function this way:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Invoicing> Invoicings()
        {
            return _repository.Invoicings.AsNoTracking();
        }
```

With the above api the below odata-query returns null from the association MyInvoice. This is also how Breeze calls the web api.

> localhost..Invoicings?$filter=SubsetLinkToPerson%20eq%2012345m&$expand=MyInvoice

But when I change the decoration of the api function to:

```
[HttpGet, Queryable]
```

Then the above odata-query retrieves and populates MyInvoice association nicely. But this still doesn't help with Breeze. It just shows that the serverside has keys and associations in place for odata to work.

Is there any way to get this work the Breeze way?